# What type of encryption is SQL Compact's "Engine Default"?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

If you specify "Engine Default" when encrypting a SQL CE database, what specific type of encryption does it use? (Let's assume version 3.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Engine Default is AES128 (it's not compatible with Windows Mobile 2003 or Windows CE 4.2)

Comment: Wikipedia says 128 bit but not what scheme. Shane, do you have a reference for your answer?

Comment: brian: No definitive reference, but these may help.
http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2007/07/31/48117.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/0120994f-807b-40d1-9e65-d1f21224980e/

Also, since DBs encrypted with "Engine Default" cannot be opened on Windows Mobile 2003 (which cannot handle AES) I am pretty certain that is what it uses.

Answer (score -2):

If it is the same as SQL Server - and I imagine it is - then it will be Triple DES

Comment: Is there a reason to assume that it is?

Comment: Well, just the assumption that they would re-use code already put in place for the main SQL Server engine.  But again, I do not know this for sure.

Comment: That's a really poor assumption, especially since the two products share zero code and are done by completely different teams.

Comment: There's no need to be rude, ctacke.  I think my answer is pretty clear that I am just passing along the encryption used in SQL Server.  Would you care to provide some reference regarding your assertion that they share "zero" code? This seems like a far more controversial claim than anything that I've said.